# What would've happened if Harry and Hermione didn't manage to return on time in the Prisoner of Azkaban?

Tags: harry-potter

When they use the time turner to save Sirius and come back, they say

> "Hermione -- what'll happen -- if we don't get back inside before Dumbledore locks the door?" Harry panted.
>
> "I don't want to think about it!" Hermione moaned, checking her watch again. "One minute!"

So what would've happened if they didn't get back inside?

Comment: Please see [GrandPa Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandfather_paradox). Since they had already changed the past in MetaTime, they couldn't not be successful, since that would make a *larger* paradox than already existed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## They'd be locked out of the hospital wing unable to sneak back in.

Harry and Hermione had to get back to the hospital wing before Dumbledore locked the door, otherwise they'd be unable to get back in, and would be caught leaving the room when they weren't supposed to.

> “Right, it’s nearly time,’ said Hermione tensely, looking at her watch. ‘We’ve got about forty-five minutes until Dumbledore locks the door to the hospital wing. We’ve got to rescue Sirius and get back into the ward before anybody realises we’re missing …”

**It seems to be against the law for Hermione to use the Time-Turner for anything other than classes.**

Hermione had a strict set of rules to follow when using the Time-Turner.

> “But remember this, both of you. You must not be seen. Miss Granger, you know the law – you know what is at stake … *you – must – not – be – seen*.”

Professor McGonagall had to write letters to the Ministry, promising that Hermione would use it responsibly, only for getting to her classes.

> “Professor McGonagall made me swear I wouldn’t tell anyone. She had to write all sorts of letters to the Ministry of Magic so I could have one. She had to tell them that I was a model student, and that I’d never, ever use it for anything except my studies …”

Using it to go against the Ministry to free Sirius Black and Buckbeak would certainly not be a Ministry-approved use.

Hermione may or may not have known what the *exact* consequences would be if she was caught misusing the Time-Turner, but she would have known it wouldn't have been good if the Ministry found out.

Comment: I have a *feeling* that this answer is not completely right, in terms of TimeTravel, but because magic, so it's correct. +1

Comment: Just add to that: As they were locked in, they were no suspects in the case of Sirius' escape.. If they were found outside of the hospital wing, everyone (especially Snape) would have suspected them to have helped Sirius...

Comment: Rich, lecturing us on lawful behavior by a convicted felon :)

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To *Knowing* the rules doesn't mean *following* them. ;)

Answer (score 2):

[This question’s answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129190/are-there-non-legal-consequences-for-wizards-that-meddle-with-time) is partly useful for this question.

As Hermione once exclaimed in *Prisoner or Azkaban*.

> Terrible things happen to wizards who meddle with time.

And "Basing off" what happens with "other Harry Potter magic", for example,
"Apparition done wrong can cause Splinching".

And (basing off the movies) Apparition and time travel have similar things which happen they both make the people dissapear and reappear somewhere else and look similar except time travel is much faster so fast that you cant see it but it could also cause theoretically cause splinching but in much more drastic ways so to answer the question.

They would have been caught but considering Dumbledore himself gave them the watch and the amount of memory altering spells there would be not too much of a problem as long as they return close enough to the hospital quarters thats out of eyes views and using a simple alohomora to get into the hospital wing when noones looking it should be fine.